# Are brass picture hooks ok for a 30lb mirror on a plaster wall?

Tags: plaster, mirror

I've got a 30 lb mirror with D-hooks on the back and cable that can take its weight appropriately. I've put this mirror up on plaster walls before but I just want to make sure because this time it's in a 120 year old building (very good condition mind you) but on a plaster wall that is above a non-working chimney, so that plaster probably has brick behind it.

I've got 50lb brass 45-degree picture hooks, I plan to use two. Is that ok or is there a better way to put this mirror up on this wall?

Comment: You did not say how you intend to fasten the hooks to the wall so we have to assume your plan is to nail them with the nails that are usually included with picture hooks. This is a BAD idea as they are likely to just pull out, and when a 30lb. mirror crashes to the floor it's a big deal. You need to use hooks that can be securely fastened with screws and anchors.

Comment: @NiallC. I was trying to reply to Jimmy Fix-it using the stackexchange app and thought I was doing so but it ended up looking like added information. Sorry, I'll go online to fix that.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Yes, it's the nails that come with the brass hooks that I was gonna use. I nailed them in, they were secure, it's definitely brick behind the plaster, you can hear it. But after putting the mirror on there for a few seconds, I just didn't feel safe about it so I took it down. And the plaster was starting to bulge under the nail.
So, then what do I need to do anhor wise. Use those thick led ones? It's only about an inch of plaster before you hit brick above this fireplace. I just need the absolutely securest thing possible. Would leaning it on the mantle be better? If you saw the w

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 alternatives as I see it: Drill holes to accommodate wall anchors using a masonry bit or use strips of two-sided adhesive to keep mirror   flush against wall, using the mantle as a base.

Answer (score 1):

There are many anchor and hook options that could work for this situation. You say you want the "securest" option, but something less than "bomb-proof" should be sufficient.

I would use anchors that are long/deep enough to actually get into the underlying brick, then use self-tapping screws to mount hooks to the wall. Two should be sufficient, positioned appropriate distance apart such that the wire is hidden and the weight is equally shared by both hooks.

[image]

[image]

Be careful to drill the proper diameter hole the appropriate depth, using a masonry drill. I use a strip of gaffer's tape around the drill bit as a marker for hole depth.

Comment: It's that bottom image of the brass hook that I was using. It's rated at 50 lbs. But something was wrong obviously because the plaster underneath was bulging ever so slightly. It didn't look safe enough so I just removed it. But the anchor I havent tried and still could. I have sveral lead anchors with screws from another apartment years ago that I never used, would that be good?

Answer (score 0):

Someone on another forum suggested concrete screws that don't need anchors. So, I got a couple that are rated for 200lb sheer load and 180lb pull. Not because the 35lb mirror needed it but because it was the lightest load I could find.

Comment: Please post the second part as a new question. Only the first part is an answer. I've edited the answer, so you can find the second part in the revision history https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/120073/revisions